# update one table depending on data on another table

Tags: php, mysql

Please can anyone help me out with php code to solve this i am new to php.I have 2 tables named "registration" table and "first_allotement" table

'registration' Table:

```
Altno | pid | appno | name | college1 | college2 | college3 | college4  | college5 | college6 | college7 | college8 | college9 | college10
```

'first_allotement' Table:

```
Altno | appno | name | college | curdate | markdate | total | pdf
```

compare 'college' field in "first_allotement" table with "registration" table fields 'college1','college2'.....'college10' if value matches with any field then update that corresponding field in "registration" table with empty value..so kindly get me a better php code to solve it

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried, show us some code please?

Comment: You should proivide some code to show us how you've attempted to solve the problem, and tell us what problems you're encountering or errors you're seeing. If your question is (or appears to be) "please write some code for me" you're unlikely to get much help.

Comment: Please take care in asking actual questions, both in title and content. This reads more like a requirement, as if you expect us to do your work.

Comment: _"kindly get me a better php code to solve it"_ you haven't provided any code so there is no "better" code. We won't do any homework for you and btw this is not a php issue but a mysql one

Answer (score 0):

Use update join :

```
update table registration join first_allotement
on registration .appno =first_allotement.appno and first_allotement.college=(registration.college1 or registration.college1 or registration.college2 or registration.college3 or registration.college4 or registration.college5 or registration.college6 or registration.college7 or registration.college8 or registration.college9 or registration.college10)
set registration.college1=null, registration.college2=null, registration.college3=null ....
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM  registration WHERE appno AND  IN(SELECT appno FROM  first_allotment)